# Does the following series of fractions of consecutive odd numbers converge? If yes, where does it converge to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I have a series of fractions that consists consecutive odd numbers in the following fashion:

$$\frac{1}{3} + \frac{3}{5} + \frac{5}{7} + \frac{7}{9} + \ ... \ = \ ?$$

My question is whether this series converges if it were to go on forever until infinity.

In my attempt, I do feel it should converge. Every term in the series is less than 1.  <strike>Moreover, as it is apparent, the sum of the first ‘n’ terms is also less than 1. So, on first look, it does seem to converge.</strike>

If that is indeed true, and the series converges, I feel it must either converge to 1 or 2. But that’s just an intuition.

---

Additionally, in my own attempt, I found that this series can be written in summation notation as follows:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n + \frac{n}{n - \frac{n}{n + n}} } = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{3}{5} + \frac{5}{7} + \frac{7}{9} + \ ... \ 
$$

---

**Edit**: The function diverges, as pointed out by many in the answers and comments. Thank you all.

Comment: Note the sequence of terms is strictly increasing so, for $n\gt 1$, the sum of $n$ terms is $\gt \frac{n}{3}$.

Comment: The terms themselves converge to $1$, so the sum diverges.  Note that $\frac 13+\frac 35 + \frac 57 \gt 1$ in contrast to your statement.

Comment: @Ross Thanks for pointing it out. I misapprehended that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a hint: notice that you can write the $n$th term as $\frac{2(n-1) + 1}{2n + 1}$ since the numerator is always the odd number directly before the denominator. From here, it is not too difficult to show that this does not converge using some series tests or by definition.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not converge. Here $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n=1$, where $a_n$ is the $n-$th term of the series, i.e., $a_n=\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}$ and now use the Divergence test.